# Copy value from different model when DjangoAdmin creates object

Tags: django

I have two models:

```
class Object(models.Model):
    object = models.CharField()
    price = models.DecimalField()

class History(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    object= models.ForeignKey(Object)
    price = models.DecimalField()
```

When I create a new history entry, I want to copy actual price from Object to History model. 
How can I do that? Need I to use specific method in view?

Comment: Where do you want to do this? Can you show your view?

Comment: I have only simple view with class, which inherits django.views.generic.View and defined here paramters: template_name = 'app/history.html' and model = History

Comment: I think @pista329's answer should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Django's [post-save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save):

Create signal receiver:

```
# models.py

def history_add_price(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.price and instance.object and instance.object.price:
        instance.price = instance.object.price
        instance.save()
    return True
```

Register signal:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models 

models.signals.post_save.connect(history_add_price, sender=History, dispatch_uid="add_price_post_save", weak=False)
```

Comment: It works. But I have a question. The price from Object should always swap the price from History (when I enter it in django admin panel). Why, when I remove condition "not instance.price" i get an error (RuntimeError maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object)

Comment: Since you have registered post_save signal on History where you are calling save() on History instance, that makes recursion.

Comment: And if I want to change value even when the value was entered in django admin? What condition have I to use to prevent from recursion failure?

Comment: To avoid recursion, you will need to change logic. For example: update History object when related Object.price is saved. There will always be recursion when save() ocurs inside of save() on same History object.

Comment: However your concept seems fine to me. History object seems to represents mark in time with forzen Object's price. No need to edit History, just create new.

Comment: If I will use update (although post_save), how can I know, that new object was created? Can you show an example?

Comment: Create and register post_save signal on Object. Same way as you use post_save on History.

Comment: These signals work on models all over your application. If you use Django Admin exclusively, you can overload HistoryAdmin.save_model() method and modify price on every save. Check docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model

Comment: One more thing. You can have `pre_save` signal on Object and create History log every time price is changed.